# How locking works in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing a program to test how a thread can keep waiting if another thread has acquired lock on same object but after looking at output I am not sure how locking works in java. Here is what i have written:

```
public class Locking {

synchronized void methodA() {
        System.out.println("inside A , " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
   new Locking().execute();
}

private void execute() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyThread());
    t1.setName("t1");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyThread());
    t2.setName("t2");

    t1.start();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    t2.start();
}

class MyThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            methodA();
        }
    }
}
```

}

I expected thread t2 to be waiting forever and program will print only

> inside A , t1

but when i run the program , I get following output:

> inside A , t1
>
> inside A , t2

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: Well, you started two separate threads each call methodA() so so the output shall be the second? Why did you expect the first result?

Comment: It would be interesting to know _why_ you expect that only t1 runs methodA. From my reading of the code, the behavior you observed makes sense. Please [edit] the question to add this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am writing a program to test how a thread can keep waiting if
>   another thread has acquired lock on same object

The single lock is here :

```
synchronized void methodA() {
        System.out.println("inside A , " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

It takes the locks on the current instance but no statement in your code locks  in a way where a thread could wait forever the lock.
Look at my comments :

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000); 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // the lock is set here
        methodA();
       // and that is released here
    }
}
```

Make the synchronized method never releases the lock and only one of the thread will be able to enter in :

```
synchronized void methodA() {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("inside A , " + Thread.currentThread()
                                                 .getName());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // handle it
        }
    }
}
```

prints :

> inside A , t1
>
> inside A , t1
>
> inside A , t1
>
> ...

Her are some other examples to play with threads.

Replace `sleep()` by `wait()` and the current thread will release the lock :

```
synchronized void methodA() {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("inside A , " + Thread.currentThread()
                                                 .getName());
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // handle it
        }
    }
}
```

prints :

> inside A , t1
>
> inside A , t2

Use `notify()` (to notify a waiting thread) and `wait()` (to make the current thread wait and release the lock if it has) to make threads collaborating between them :

```
synchronized void methodA() {
    while (true) {
        notify();
        System.out.println("inside A , " + Thread.currentThread()
                                                 .getName());
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // handle it
        }
    }
}
```

prints :

> inside A , t1
>
> inside A , t2
>
> inside A , t1
>
> inside A , t2
>
> ...

Answer (score 0):

That is intended situation.

Your t1 thread is waiting in another thread not main thread.

In your main thread(make threads and call start()), just waiting 5 seconds and start thread2

your synchronized method is synchronizing only when thread 1 calls that method not forever.

After thread1 calls synchorinized method and return, thread1 is stopping 5seconds.

In that time, thread2 can use that method.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `synchronized` infront of a method means, that the method cannot be called by two threads at the same time.

As soon as the method is called by a thread, other threads trying to call that same method are blocked until the first thread returns from that method. Afterwards the other threads calling the same method can automatically continue with the call (one at a time).

Answer (score 0):

You implicit lock with `synchronized` is working for a short period - that is the `println` after that the lock is released. Both of your threads are racing to obtain the lock there.

Change your code to this and you will see the behavior you want

```
class MyThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
            methodA();
    }
}

synchronized void methodA() {
        while(true)
        System.out.println("inside A , " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```